# In DirectX 12, how performant is it to switch Pipeline State Objects?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, gpu, directx-12

I'm researching DirectX 12 and I'm wondering how performant it is to switch pipeline state objects.. I'm getting conflicting reports from the sources I'm reading, i.e. some are saying that it is very slow and others are saying that it is quite fast.

The "slow" argument used is: the GPU has to do a bunch of stuff under the hood such as recompilations etc whenever you use `SetPipelineState()`.

The "fast" argument used is: all the computations for the pipeline state are done upon creation of the the pipeline state object, therefore the GPU can just swap around some pointers and that's it.

Which is true? How performant is `SetPipelineState()` and what should I keep in mind when using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fast answer, you will probably never have a performance issue with switching PSO, that is how they were design in the first place.

For a bit longer answer, the cost of a change of pipeline state object will depends mainly on three criteria :

- The hardware and driver efficiency.
- The pipeline stages that are about to turn on or off, like the tesselation unit.
- The root signature, because it is close but still an abstraction, the driver may have some work to prepare a mapping of it.

PSO are designed to be as fast as possible to switch, it is self content, and, at least on nVidia and AMD, the only shader compilation happen at the creation, never at the usage. On AMD, it is even possible to extract the real microcode assembly with a bit of a hack from the result of `ID3D12PipelineState::GetCachedBlob`. One observation was that they do not use a fetch shader system anymore like on DX11 to deal with different input layouts as it is now part of the PSO description.

It has to be mentioned that a big strength of DX12 is also to provide access to bindless resources. With that feature, it is possible to drop the amount of material flushes by a factor ten or so, using clever instancing and `ExecuteIndirect`, you can let the GPU decide materials and geometry without much interaction.

Because the information is public somehow (http://www.wihlidal.ca/Presentations/GDC_2016_Compute.pdf).

> On    Xbox    One,    ExecuteIndirect has some    incredible  extensions  where   PSOs    can be  switched    by  indirect    arguments,  meaning we  can issue   a   single  ExecuteIndirect for our entire  scene,  regardless  of  state   or
>   resource  changes.

A PSO change on Xbox One is virtually free on the CPU because they are able to consume them from the GPU directly. It is sad that it is not available on PC, but it should help you lower your concern about PSO switches.

Answer (score 1):

Real question is: what do you use SetPipelineState() for? You can't change shaders without it. You can's change resource binding configuration. You can't change topology otherwise. In theory PipelineState has all of the stuff that should be needed to program GPU, and you can't swap blocks in here, so you are kind of stuck with what you have.

Now to answer: it depends on GPU and driver. Yes, there is some stuff done in the background. However, decent graphics driver should optimize, and cache what was already done. Meaning - if you already used given PipelineState, using different one and going back to original one should be fast.

Comment: The whole purpose of the immutable PSO model is to put as much of the 'overhead' cost at creation time as possible. There's very little the driver has to do when you go to set it because all the required validation was done before-hand. The real challenge is making sure you are able to create all the PSOs you need ahead of time rather than doing it 'on-demand'. Creating a PSO is very costly; using a PSO is very cheap (by design).

Comment: Also, why exactly are you using DirectX 12 rather than DirectX 11? Are you already pushing DirectX 11 to the point that the CPU overhead of the runtime is your bottleneck? DirectX 12 is awesome for expert graphics developers who want total control over the hardware, but that control comes at the cost of having the application do *everything* that the DirectX 11 Runtime takes care of on your behalf: synchronization, video memory management including in constrained scenarios, state object caching, etc.